# CSS Positions and dynamic height for container

Tags: html, css

you want the container to shrink or expand when you click next?I have created one fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/agriz/nS8M3/1/
I am forced to give height for these two elements `<div class="slider"> <ul>`

I would like to have automatic height for these two containers.
If we mix relative and absolute positions, is it possible to have dynamic height for the containers?

I searched in SO and found this one: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/zVBDc/

Here too the container has the height property in css.

HTML PART

```
<div class="slider">
  <ul>
    <li class="active"><img src="http://i41.tinypic.com/10rok86.jpg" class="slider_img" />  </li>
    <li><img src="http://i40.tinypic.com/f0rfag.jpg" class="slider_img" /></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="toolbars">
  <button onClick="window.slider.previous()">Previous</button>
  <button onClick="window.slider.next()">Next</button>
</div>
```

I want the container to shrink or expand when I click next (copied from a comment!)

Comment: What do you mean by automatic height? Do you want the height to fill the screen, only take up half, or what? Technically, you *already* have automatic height by default: the height will expand to contain its contents.

Comment: No. It is not expanding. In the fiddle, I have given static height for container `div.slider`. If you remove the height, you will see, it is not expanding till the contents.

Comment: Absolute positioning takes elements out of the “flow”, so that they can not affect the height of their parent any more.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding.  Are you saying that you want the container to shrink or expand when you click next?  http://jsfiddle.net/zGpKa/

Comment: The `<ul>` is the parent for the `<li>` and li has absolute position and ul has relative position. So, Will ul change its height according to the lists? In my case it is not.

Comment: @ChrisLively Yes, You are exactly correct!

Comment: @ChrisLively You fiddle is good. It works well when i change the `var transition = 500;` to 0 in js. For the fade effects, it is not good. It has problem because of the relative position of lists

Comment: @ChrisLively You answer helped me. Post it as an answer, so i can accept it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See fiddle for possible answer.   http://jsfiddle.net/zGpKa

I made the following change to your CSS.

```
.slider li {
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: none;
}
```